# Code snippet over a black background in Emacs Muse

Tags: html, emacs

I have the following Emacs Muse snippet:

```
   <src lang="cc">
      int a = 1;
   </src>
```

This "htmlizes" the code within the angle brackets (adding color to keywords, etc.). The problem is that my font faces are optimized for a black Emacs background. How can I tell Muse to output the code over a black background?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is really not problem of Muse, but of htmlize package. It looks for `face-background` property of given face, so you need to check, which background is set for `default` face and for `font-lock-*` faces... Please, check also htmlize's version